# If won't trigger inside while

Tags: c, microcontroller, attiny

currently I'm trying my best at programming a microcontroller.

```
int main()
{
    init_ports();

    while(1){
        if(gameStatus == 1){
            gameStatus = 2;
            beep(120);
        }
    }
}
```

is my main, gameStatus is a global uint_8. It gets set by an interrupt that is caused by pressing a button.

```
ISR(INT0_vect){
    if(gameStatus == 0)
        gameStatus = 1; // that works

}
```

The main however won't recognize gameStatus at all. Is there a reason why this could be?

Thanks!

Comment: make sure the interrupt is actually being run, and it sets gameStatus to 1

Comment: When you say it will not recognise `gameStatus`, does it fail to compile?  A possibility is that you have a global initialised to zero (default) and it is not getting set to 1 for some reason.

Comment: and what does the ISR do when `gameStatus == 2` as set in `main`? What does "not recognize" mean? That it does not compile?

Comment: `volatile sig_atomic_t` could help here.

Comment: volatile helped :) now it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to wildplasser!

Changing

```
uint8_t gameStatus = 0;
```

into

```
volatile uint8_t gameStatus = 0;
```

did the trick.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_(computer_programming)